# C# Covariance / Contravariance in IEnumerable<T> where T is generic type, interface vs class

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance

does someone understand why having a generic where constraint as class is different than interface? This code does not compile:

```
public interface IInterface
{
}

public class Class<T> where T : IInterface
{
    public void Do()
    {
        IEnumerable<IInterface> ret = GetEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerable()
    {
        return new T[0];
    }
}
```

whereas, by changing IInterface to class, suddenly compiles

```
public class IInterface
{
}

public class Class<T> where T : IInterface
{
    public void Do()
    {
        IEnumerable<IInterface> ret = GetEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerable()
    {
        return new T[0];
    }
}
```

I know that I can use:

```
IEnumerable<IInterface> ret = (IEnumerable<IInterface>)GetEnumerable();
```

but I really would like to know the reason why is the cast necessary if IInterface is interface.

Comment: "This code does not compile" - it would help other people if you *provided the error message(s)* rather than expecting us to guess or have to run the code ourselves.

Comment: This scenario is discussed specifically in the MS Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Answer (score 3):

The real question is, is it really necessary?

`T`, in this specific case, should always be a class.

You can ensure that by additionally adding the `class` constraint.

```
public interface IInterface
{
    bool Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Class<T> where T : class, IInterface
{
    public void Do()
    {
        var ret = GetEnumerable();

        foreach (var item in ret)
        {
            item.Foo = true; // you can handle the object just if you would have an object of that type.
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerable()
    {
        return new T[0];
    }
}
```

Now if you remove the class constraint it would still work. However, if you hover over the squigglies of that `item.Foo = true` it will come apparent why:

[image]

Comment: thank you, great answer, "class constraint" is the right thing

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance#generic-interfaces-with-covariant-type-parameters):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

With your interface example, there is no such constraint on `T`, whereas with the class example this constraint is inferred.

If you need to constrain to an interface, an additional "reference type constraint" is required:

```
public class Class<T> where T : class, IInterface
```

Comment: thank you, great answer, "class constraint" is the right thing