# Using generics with IEnumerable in base class constructor

Tags: c#, generics

Why does this code gives this error?

> Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' is not
> assignable to parameter type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<[...].IExample>'

```cs
public interface IExample { }

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(IEnumerable<IExample> a) { }
}

public class FailingClass<T> : BaseClass
    where T : IExample
{
    public FailingClass(IEnumerable<T> a): base(a) { } //error here on base(a)
}
```

Comment: Using the `class` constraint on `T` helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Covariance / Contravariance in IEnumerable<T> where T is generic type, interface vs class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71408201/c-sharp-covariance-contravariance-in-ienumerablet-where-t-is-generic-type-i)

Comment: So yeah, learn about covariance and contravariance, but replacing the base call like so will allow it to compile `base(a.Cast<IExample>())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `class` constraint to `T` within `FailingClass`.
`IEnumerable<T>` has a type parameter marked as covariant. Covariance enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified. Variance in general applies to reference types only.

So what the class constraint actually does here is enforcing a constraint to pass a reference type. If you were to pass in a value type for T, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type and does not suffice `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IExample { }

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(IEnumerable<IExample> a) { }
}

public class FailingClass<T> : BaseClass
    where T : class, IExample
{
    public FailingClass(IEnumerable<T> a): base(a) { } //error here on base(a)
}
```